# Button click in android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I have created android wear activity with a small button (A shortcut to activity in my mobile app). Is it possible to send a bundle request to my main app?

If so how to implement the click listener?

Thanks!

Comment: did you read the doc ? http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using mentioned MessageApi: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html
You need to initialize and connect with GoogleApiClient. Once you clicks the button you have to get list of nodes and send a message to them. The last step is to read this message fron phone part of app, this can be done by registering proper WearableListenerService. Please see the sample code below.

**Wearable part of app:**
Please define such Activity on your Wearable part of app:

```
public class WearableButtonActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wearable_button_activity);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View target) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
            return;

        final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);
        nodes.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result) {
                final List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++) {
                        final Node node = nodes.get(i);

                        // You can just send a message
                        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/MESSAGE", null);

                        // or you may want to also check check for a result:
                        // final PendingResult<SendMessageResult> pendingSendMessageResult = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/MESSAGE", null);
                        // pendingSendMessageResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                        //      public void onResult(SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                        //          if (sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode()==WearableStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                        //              // do something is successed
                        //          }
                        //      }
                        // });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and attack onButtonClick method to your button in your res/layout/wearable_button_activity.xml file:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onButtonClicked" />
```

**OR** just set OnClickListener from code if you like that way:

```
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });
```

**Phone part of app:**
Then declare DataLayerListenerService on yout phone's manifest:

```
<service android:name=".DataLayerListenerService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

DataLayerListenerService class:

```
public class DataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        if("/MESSAGE".equals(messageEvent.getPath())) {
            // launch some Activity or do anything you like
        }
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: Both parts of your app need to have **the same package name** to contact with each other.

Comment: You need to specify android:onClick value in xml layout file
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked" />

Or you can just setOnClickListener from code.

Comment: answer edited to cover this part.

Comment: Actually I figured that out. THanks for the quick reply. Can you please let me know what happens when the device is not connected to phone? The Emulator still send a log message after the for loop. According to the cord it shouldn't do anything right?

Comment: If phone is not connected Message will be ignored. If you want something that will be saved and delivered to Android Wear after it gets connected you should use DataApi instead of MessageApi, but in this case I don't see the use case why someone would want to save such result for later and launch an activity once watch will be conntected to phone again...

If you want to check the result of sending a message you can do similar mechanism with "PendingResult", as done while obtaining Nodes. Then in the callback you can check the result.

Comment: I require the messageAPI.. But then I am giving a finish and Toast once I press the button. In this case. I get a toast even if the device is not connected. How do I handle that part?

Comment: As I said i previous comment - you have to check the result of sending message. I've updated the answer.

Comment: BTW. when no devices are connected the "nodes" List should be empty. You can just check whether it is empty and do not need to perform a for loop anyway and just return before it.

Comment: If I use something like what you have given I get Unreachable statement for: "final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);"

Comment: Probably you haven't initialize your mGoogleApiClient variable...
Are you 100% sure that you use exactly the code I've given? Did you changed anything or so?

Comment: It is initialized. Same. 100%

Comment: Can you post the full me code of your activity? You said that you'are showing toasts etc so I guess your code is not the same in 100%.

Comment: I have used toast in the place where you have said do soemthing if sucess

Comment: Never mind I am using variable if not sucess toast something else.

Comment: But you've just said that you have "Unreachable statement for: "final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);" - the Toast displaying if far after that... So displaying toast is not affesting this issue in any way. I do not understans what is your problem now?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed the new code you suggested and used your first code and then checked if nodes are 0 then say try again.... Thanks a lot this worked for me.

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga i use your code, but it not work for me. The listener service  does not start

Comment: @Garf1eld The code above is correct - I have tested it. Please make sure that your applications has the same package name and both devices are paired and connected properly. Do notifications from other apps are displayed on the Android Wear device?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga i have 2 modules in project:
mobile and
wear.
In gradle.build & in manifest pacage is same.
If i trying to send notification from handheld to wear it works.
On my phone in `Android wear` application `host` and `target` is connected.
I cant send any notification to mobile from wear.
Also in setting (on mobile) notificstions is not banned.
I can post my code or whole project. By e-mail or etc (not GitHub)

Comment: Wait. You are trying to send `notifications` or `messages`? In the code above there is no use of `notifications`. You also said that the methods in `WearableListenerService` are not being invoked. Have you checked the status while sending the message? Is at least one `node` available? Is message sent successfully etc?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga I'm trying to send a `message` from `wear` to `phone`. Status is `Success` but  `resolution` is `null`. Method `getNodes` returns one node.
Thre is    link to project on GitHub   (i registered especially)
 https://github.com/Garf1eldGit/MessageApiTrying

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga i edited my code (copied your code completely).
https://github.com/Garf1eldGit/MessageApiTrying/tree/experiment
Please look on it and tell me what wrong
 StatusCode is `Success` but `resolution` is null