# Android Wear Message API unknown error code 4004

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have the following block of code to sent a message to my device, but the message is not getting sent... I do not have any idea why...

Here is the code in which I build my GoogleApiClient:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d("dirk", "Google API Client connected");
                    sendMessage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.d("dirk", "Google API Client disconnected, cause: " + cause);
                    mConnected = false;
                    mConnecting = false;
                    // TODO handle disconnect
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d("dirk", "Google API Client connection failed, reason: " + result);
                    mConnected = false;
                    mConnecting = false;
                    // TODO handle connection failure
                }
            })
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
```

And here is my code that is getting called from the sendMessage method:

```
Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(getClient(), nodeId, PATH, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<SendMessageResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
            if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.d("dirk", "message could not be sent: " + sendMessageResult.getStatus().toString());
                Log.d("dirk", "Client connected: " + getClient().isConnected());
                // TODO show communication error
            }
        }
    });
```

The logging is here:

```
Google API Client connected
message could not be sent: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 4004, resolution=null}
Client connected: true
```

So all conditions seem to be fine, but the unknown error code 4004 cannot be resolved (at least I did not find anything wrong so far).
Anyone an idea what could be the reason of this?

Dirk

Comment: You didn't posted what value is passed in nodeId variable in sendMessage method. Are you sure it's valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a documentation that supports my previous assumptions from comment above. Please take a look at `WearableStatusCodes` class - it contains status codes used in WearableApi method results.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableStatusCodes.html#INVALID_TARGET_NODE

So this error is no longer "unknown":) - `4004` is a code for `INVALID_TARGET_NODE`.
Please check what value you pass in `nodeId` variable.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow morning, but I think I was using the Node.getId() as input. Thx for the reply and if correct I mark it as correct tomorrow!

Comment: No problem. Everything else looks fine. Apart from "connect()" method on GoogleApiClient object is not present - but from your logs it seems that you invoked it somewhere:) The final question is what is this "node" that you're obtaining id (getId()) from. I hope it's a valid node and not a sender node (don't know if sending messages to sender node itself is allowed:)

Comment: Could already check it :-) The value passed as node id was indeed incorrect. My bad. Great that you found the status codes :-) The docs are sometimes a bit confusing at this early stage. Thanks for your help! Now the next part is letting my phone receive the message (that doesn't seem to work yet ;-) ).

Comment: Glad I could help:) I've found the status codes while answering another question. By the way I've posted a full code to send a receive messages from Wear to Phone. Basically the message is send to all connected nodes (Don't know it phone is always the only one? but there is no API to get only phone's nodeId). Take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711232/button-click-in-android-wear/24711474#24711474

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga can you hepl me?
In my app using message api `Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}`
 byt `  applicationId ` in gradle is similar in `mobile` and `wear` package.
how to solve?