# Trigger action from android wear on mobile

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I want to have a button on Android wear which clicked will send some data onto the paired mobile.
I know how to call an event from mobile to wear using MessageApi. However I cant do the reverse.

Please help.
Thank You

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595170/sending-messages-from-android-wear-to-host-device)? It might help.

Comment: Sending data from Wearable app to mobile is done the same way as the opposite. Just swap the roles. Please also see a working code posted in my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24711474/3827276. It demonstrates exactly your case - to send message from Android Wear (after clicking a button) and receive it on Android Phone.

Comment: thanks. it is exactly the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in the same way. It doesn't matter which direction you are going.