# Executeing a method in Handheld class from Wear Module Android

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Let's say I have a Method in MainActivity called `Emergencyalert()`, what it dose is, it sends some alert message to some selected contacts. So I wanted a wear app which dose nothing but just execute the `Emergencyalert()` Method in Handheld Device, When the user click on a Emergency button in Android Wear.
There are two different modules in my project called mobile and wear. I use AndroidStudio. Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First move your `Emergencyalert()` method into a service (an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) would be perfect for this: just have your `Emergencyalert()` code run in the service's `onHandleIntent()`). This is necessary since methods in your activity can only be called when your activity is open and visible on screen (which wouldn't be the case when activated via your Wear app).

You can test to make sure your `IntentService` is working by replacing your call to `Emergencyalert()` in your `MainActivity` with a call to

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmergencyAlertIntentService.class));
```

This will start the service and do your emergency alert.

For the Android Wear portion, your Wear app needs to [send a Message](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to your handheld device, stating that the emergency button was pressed. You should then implement a [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) in your handheld app and override the [onMessageReceived()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onMessageReceived(com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent)) method - in that method, call the same `startService()` you called in your `MainActivity` and your emergency alert will fire even when your app is in the background when you hit the button on the Android Wear device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed http://stackoverflow.com/a/24711474/2102794. Both methods works fine for me..